# Binding enter key conflicts with alert popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user presses the Enter key anywhere on the `body`, it triggers the click event on another element which in turn opens a basic alert popup (for testing purposes).

This creates a loop because pressing Enter again will close the alert but will trigger the event again, opening a new alert, and the cycle repeats.

---

I'm using this in a modal box script. When the modal box appears, the user can press Enter to perform the action that a button inside the modal box would do, such as closing it (or in my case, opening an alert popup).

The click code:

```
//Add click events...
button.bind('click', mybtn, function(e) {
    var click;

    if (e.data.onclick) {
        e.data.onclick(e);
    } else if (e.data.click) {
        e.data.click(e);
    }
});
```

The key code:

```
//Add key events...
$('body').keyup(mybtn, function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    //What key we need to match...
    switch (e.data.key) {
        case 'enter':
            if (keyCode == 13)          e.data.button.trigger('click');
            break;

        case 'esc':
        case 'escape':
            if (keyCode == 27)          e.data.button.trigger('click');
            break;
    }
});
```

---

Should I bind my events in a different place (element)? Is there a better way to bind to stop this loop?

I can't unbind the key event because my script needs to be flexible enough to handle multiple key presses.

---

Example of creating a modal box:

```
createModal('HTML <b>content</b>', [{ label: 'Close', onclick: function() { alert('Modal closed'); }, key: 'enter' }]);
```

The HTML content is dumped into the modal, then the function will loop through the controls you've defined and will try to build them for you. In this example you define a "close" control, which would look like this (if you used `onclick=""`):

`<button onclick="function() { alert('Modal closed'); }">Close</button>`

with an event assigned to the document that when you press Enter it will trigger clicking that button, causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
button.one('click', mybtn, function(e) {
    var click;

    if (e.data.onclick) {
        e.data.onclick(e);
    } else if (e.data.click) {
        e.data.click(e);
    }
});
```

Will limit the click event to only one occurrence and then it unbinds itself.

Comment: What if I want to be able to click the button multiple times? For example if the modal contains live content and the button triggers a refresh?

Comment: If the page reloads, the event is recreated and the handler is re-bound.

Comment: @DevIshOne I know but that's not how events should work. It's supposed to be asynchronous, so not requiring a page reload.

Comment: When I commented with "refresh" I meant refreshing the live content in the modal box with AJAX.

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant a page refresh. Why not place a separate button INSIDE the dialog box to refresh it's data?

Comment: @DevIshOne I could but the script I've written is designed to simplify this process though. You pass it a label and function (that would perform the refresh) and it does all of the button construction and binding.

Comment: You're going to have to fiddle it. Now I'm lost as to what's inside the modal, what's causing the simple alert to be rendered and what's refreshing the info inside the modal. It sounds like you've painted yourself into a corner.

Comment: @DevIshOne Those were examples. My script should be flexible enough to handle any type of control, keys being pressed to trigger those controls and the content of the modal is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Edited my question with an example of creating the modal.

Comment: Sorry, without the fiddle it is far too hard to follow. Maybe you need to find a way to check and see if the modal exists and determine where you want the `ENTER` key to act from there.

Comment: I would usually post the full source-code, but it's out of my control and a bit too complicated. Sorry.